# Unable to bind MVC model property to input element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm having trouble getting my model to bind to an input box created by a custom helper method. I wrapped a jquery ajax-driven autocomplete box with a helper method called "Html.AutoCompleteBoxAjax." This helper basically just creates an  element with javascript autocomplete functionality.

The property in the model is a string called "formatName". I have verified that, in the generated html for the view, both the name and id of the input element are "formatName",  and that there are no other elements with those identities. I've also checked that the model has a default constructor, and that the "formatName" property is publicly accessible. Lastly, I've verified that when the Channel model is passed into the view, Channel.formatName has the correct value. Yet despite all this, I can't get the value to bind to the  element, and the input box remains blank. There is also no binding when going the other way, from view to controller, and Channel.formatName remains blank.

What am I missing? Is it somehow because I'm using a custom helper method?

**Model:**

```
namespace WebApp.Models
{
    public class ChannelModel
    {
        XYZ.DataAccess.ODS.DB db = Config.DB();

        public string id { get; set; }

        // Parent Project
        [Display(Name = "Project")]
        public string projectID { get; set; }

        // Format Name
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Format is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(Constants.username_regex, ErrorMessage = Constants.username_regexErrorMsg)]
        [Display(Name = "Format")]
        public string formatName { get; set; }

        // Channel Name
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Channel name is required.")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = Constants.minLengthErrorMsg, MinimumLength = Constants.username_minLength)]
        [RegularExpression(Constants.username_regex, ErrorMessage = Constants.username_regexErrorMsg)]
        [Display(Name = "Channel name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        // Sequence
        [Display(Name = "Sequence")]
        public string sequenceID { get; set; }

        public ChannelModel()
        {
            id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        public ChannelModel(XYZ.DataAccess.ODS.Channel channel_db)
        {
            id = channel_db.id;
            projectID = channel_db.project_id;
            name = channel_db.name;
            formatName = channel_db.format_name;
            sequenceID = channel_db.sequence_id;
        }

        public XYZ.DataAccess.ODS.Channel buildDBObject()
        {
            XYZ.DataAccess.ODS.Channel channel = new XYZ.DataAccess.ODS.Channel();
            channel.id = id;
            channel.project_id = projectID;
            channel.name = name;
            channel.format_name = formatName;
            channel.sequence_id = sequenceID;
            return channel;
        }
    }


}
```

**View**

```
@model WebApp.Models.ChannelModel
@using HelperMethods.Infrastructure

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";

    var sequences = ViewData["sequences"] as List<SelectListItem>;
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@section header {
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Channel</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.projectID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.name)

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name):
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Format")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.AutoCompleteBoxAjax("formatName", Url.Action("GetFormatsBeginningWith"))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.formatName)
        </div>

        <!-- SEQUENCE -->
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Sequence")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.SlaveDropdownList("sequenceID", "groupID", Url.Action("GetSequencesInGroup"), WebApp.Util.makeSelectList(sequences, Model.sequenceID))
        </div>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
    public class ChannelController : Infrastructure.NoCacheController
    {
        XYZ.DataAccess.ODS.DB db = Config.DB();

        -- stuff --

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetFormatsBeginningWith(string term)
        {
            var formats = db.getFormatsBeginningWith(term);

            List<CustomHelpers.AutocompleteItem> items = new List<CustomHelpers.AutocompleteItem>();
            foreach (var format in formats)
                items.Add(new CustomHelpers.AutocompleteItem { value = format.name, label = format.name });

            var j = Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return j;
        }


        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            ChannelModel channelModel = new ChannelModel(db.getChannel(id));

            string groupID = db.getProject(channelModel.projectID).group_id;
            var sequences = db.getSequencesInGroup(groupID);
            ViewData["sequences"] = makeSelectListItems(sequences);

            return View(channelModel);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Channel/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(ChannelModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.updateChannel(model.buildDBObject());

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            string groupID = db.getProject(model.projectID).group_id; 
            var sequences = db.getSequencesInGroup(groupID);
            ViewData["sequences"] = makeSelectListItems(sequences);

            return View(model);
        }

        -- more stuff --
    }
}
```

**Helper method for AutoCompleteBox**

```
    public static MvcHtmlString AutoCompleteBoxAjax(this HtmlHelper html, string id, string actionUrl)
    {
        TagBuilder input = new TagBuilder("input");
        input.Attributes.Add("id", id);
        input.Attributes.Add("name", id);
        input.Attributes.Add("type", "text");
        input.AddCssClass("autocomplete_ajax");
        input.Attributes.Add("value", "");
        input.Attributes.Add("action", actionUrl);

        var variables = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            {"AUTOCOMPLETE_ID", id}
        };

        var script = populateScriptTemplate("TEMPLATE_autocomplete_ajax.js", variables);

        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.AppendLine(input.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
        s.AppendLine(script);

        return new MvcHtmlString(s.ToString());
    }
```

**Javascript for the autocomplete**

```
$('#AUTOCOMPLETE_ID').autocomplete({
    source: $('#AUTOCOMPLETE_ID').attr('action')
    });
```

**Relevant portion of the view's html**

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input action="/Channel/GetFormatsBeginningWith" class="autocomplete_ajax" id="formatName" name="formatName" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="formatName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: When you are pre-populating inputs and other form elements it is responsibility of the helper to set the value properly. There is no 'after processing' that would take care of this or any automatic process. I'd recommend calling a built-in TextBox / TextBoxFor helper from your AutoCompleteBoxAjax and only pre-populate parameters for it.

Comment: Oh, of course. Somehow I'd gotten it my head that the reason why helpers were defined as extension methods was to preserve some mechanism by which the binding magically took place. Obvious in retrospect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer turned out to be simple with input from @Jakub. The helper itself has to populate the value; there's no automatic binding that takes place for html helpers. Once I took care of this, the auto binding of posts back to the controller worked as expected.